# почему не всегда генерируется рандомная строка

Tags: c++

```
char* randomStrGen(int length)
{
    static int inc = 2;
    inc++;
    srand((unsigned)GetTickCount() % 10000* (inc+inc));

    static std::string charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    std::string result;
    result.resize(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        result[i] = charset[rand() % charset.length()];
    
    char* Cresult=(char*)malloc(result.size()+1);
    strcpy(Cresult, result.c_str());
    return Cresult;
}
```

Сделал алгоритм для генерации рандомной строки,но как бы я ни старался при нескольких друг подряд идущих вызовах(в моем случае создаются 2 потока и в них вызывается),генерируется одинаковая строка.Почему,ведь я добавил в инициализатор srand число которое добавляет уникальность каждому вызову и по сути при каждом вызове srand должна инициализироваться разным числом.

Comment: Вероятно, у вас плохая хеш функция) GetTickCount - это же миллисекунды?

Comment: @vp_arth правильно,но ведь там переменная есть которая как никак уникальна при каждом вызове

Comment: Обычная переменная, читают одновременно, потом инкрементят) Попробуйте `std::atomic<int>`

Comment: @vp_arth то есть проблема в том что что потоки вызывают эту функцию одновременно  ?

Comment: Других причин получить то же зерно для srand не видно. Вообще, странный у вас c++, скорее С какой-то) `char *`, `malloc`, зачем это всё? Почему бы не вернуть result?

Comment: @vp_arth потому что нужна си-строка

Comment: @vp_arth ну можно и так)

Comment: Не, нельзя, копировать надо всё равно. Что там с генерацией? атомик не зашёл?

Comment: @vp_arth да не понятно пока)Врода все правильно заработало,решил посмотреть как раньше со static было , и там тоже все правильно заработало) Но я думаю ваш вариант в любом случае лучше

Comment: Можно ещё `this_thread::get_id()` посолить) А лучше перенести srand в main, и больше никогда его не вызывать)

Comment: @Harry, зря закрыли вопрос как дубликат. В данном конкретном случае, вызвать `srand` один раз где-нибудь в начале `main` может не помочь в генерации не повторяющихся значений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить

```
static int inc = 2;
inc++;
```

на

```
static std::atomic<int> id{0}; // #include <atomic>
int inc = id.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) + 1;
```

Или вообще уберите лишние вызовы `srand`, достаточно посеять seed однажды, в main.

Comment: Я пробовал устанавливать seed 1 раз,результат был нехороший) такие же одинаковые строки

Comment: Это очень странно =)

Comment: 1) Стандарт языка не гарантирует, что функции `srand\rand` — потокобезопасны. [c.math.rand](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.math.rand#3). 2) В libc эти функции потокобезопасны, и вызов `srand` в любом из потоков влияет на все потоки. [Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42260c0d44c26791). 3) В  C runtime library от Microsoft каждый поток хранит собственный экземпляр внутреннего состояния функций `srand/rand`, и вызов этих функций в других потоках никак не повлияет на текущий. [Пример](https://rextester.com/GLAW44714).

Comment: @wololo, ну это ладно. Но как может не работать единственный вызов в порождающем/главном потоке? У каждого rand своя копия генератора? Upd: посмотрел примеры, понятно)

Comment: Как конкретно это реализовано — нужно смотреть исходники. Но вот цитата из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/srand?view=vs-2019): "The srand function sets the starting point for generating a series of pseudorandom integers **in the current thread**".